# How to assert that a struct's associated constant satisfies a condition?

Tags: generics, rust, serde

I have a generic function `serialize` that serializes a struct implementing `serde::Serialize` together with a custom trait `MaxSize` to a byte buffer. The `MaxSize` trait is implemented with a derive macro, and has an associated constant `MAX_SIZE` that gets filled in with the maximum possible size the struct serializes to.

I want to get an error at compile time if `serialize` is called on a struct whose `MAX_SIZE` is larger than some constant, `MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE`. (The idea is to prevent creating structs that could exceed the max UDP datagram size when serialized.) How do I do this? I've tried the following (omitting the derive macro here and instead just filling in `MAX_SIZE` for the example struct manually for simplicity) ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c4e6f66b2021c8b69faab008acbc4def)):

```rust
const MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE: usize = 100;

trait MaxSize {
    const MAX_SIZE: usize;
}

#[derive(serde::Serialize)]
struct ExampleStruct {
    a: f64,
}

// (This would actually be implemented using a derive macro.)
impl MaxSize for ExampleStruct {
    const MAX_SIZE: usize = 7;
}

fn serialize<T: serde::Serialize + MaxSize>(data: &T, buf: &mut [u8]) {
    const _: () = assert!(T::MAX_SIZE < MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE);
    // <code to actually serialize>
}

fn main() {
    serialize(&ExampleStruct {a: 6.}, &mut [0u8; MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE]);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0401]: can't use generic parameters from outer function
  --> src/main.rs:18:27
   |
17 | fn serialize<T: serde::Serialize + MaxSize>(data: &T, buf: &mut [u8]) {
   |              - type parameter from outer function
18 |     const _: () = assert!(T::MAX_SIZE < MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE);
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^ use of generic parameter from outer function
```

Comment: Might be relevant: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/const-generics-where-restrictions/12742

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On stable:

```rust
struct Const<T>(std::marker::PhantomData<T>);
impl<T: MaxSize> Const<T> {
    const C: () = assert!(T::MAX_SIZE < MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE);
}
fn serialize<T: serde::Serialize + MaxSize>(data: &T, buf: &mut [u8]) {
    [Const::<T>::C; 1];
    // <code to actually serialize>
}
```

On nightly:

```rust
#![feature(inline_const)]

fn serialize<T: serde::Serialize + MaxSize>(data: &T, buf: &mut [u8]) {
    const { assert!(T::MAX_SIZE < MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE) };
    // <code to actually serialize>
}
```

Note that both generate a **post-monomorphization** error, meaning they'll succeed `cargo check` but fail `cargo build`, and so are discouraged to use (but can be used nonetheless).